# Implementing a generic Utility class in Business Logic Layer to communicate with DAL

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, n-tier-architecture

The following is a fragment of my Database tables:

Account
--------------------------
       Account_Id
       Account_Types
       Customer_Id
       Row_Guid

Customer
--------------------------
       Customer_Id
       First_Name
       Last_Name
       Balance
       Row_Guid

Order
--------------------------
       Order_Id
       Customer_id
       Row_Guid

I have generated the classes using Entity Framework. After that, I started writing a utility class in Business logic layer that will communicate with the presentation layer to perform addition deletion, etc. For example, when the user clicks on "Add" button in the form the event will call a method from this utility class.

Since the functionality is similar for all tables I though I can make a generic interface then let the each Table specific utility class implement it.

I have the following:
`BillingDBEntities` is the generated class by the entity framework which contains all the "domain objects". This class has inner objects such as: ACCOUNT, CUSTOMER, .. which represents the database tables.

This is my utility interface:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.Objects.DataClasses;
using DataAccessLayer;
namespace BusinessLogicLayer.Implementations
{
    public interface IUtility<T> where T : EntityObject
    {
        void AddEntity(BillingDBEntities billingEntity, T item);
        void AddEntity(BillingDBEntities billingEntity, object[] items, Type[] types);

        void RemoveEntity(BillingDBEntities billingEntity, T item);
        void RemoveEntity(BillingDBEntities billingEntity, object[] items, Type[] types);

        void UpdateEntity(BillingDBEntities billingEntity, object[] items, Type[] types);
     }
}
```

For methods like void `AddEntity(BillingDBEntities billingEntity, T item);` T will be simply replaced with ACCOUNT, ORDER, CUSTOMER, etc. But for methods like void

```
AddEntity(BillingDBEntities billingEntity, object[] items, Type[] types);
```

the items array contains the components of the type. For Account it will contain (Account_id, Customer_id, Account_type, Row_guid) and the types array contains the types of the components for example for the account it will be (long, long,long ,Guid).

```
public class Utility : IUtility<ACCOUNT>
    {
        public void AddEntity(BillingDBEntities billingEntity, ACCOUNT item)
        {
            billingEntity.ACCOUNTS.AddObject(item);
        }
        public void AddEntity(BillingDBEntities billingEntity, object[] items, Type[] types)
        {
            //What should I write here????
        }
..
.
.
.
}
```

Question: How can I implement the method? How the `BillingDBEntities` will be called inside the method to set the object variables? Is there a way that instead of creating Utility, Utility , ... I can create only one class ?

If my interface has a wrong design or if there is well-known way to implement such task please tell me.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What you are doing is creating a generic repository for Entity Framework.  If you search on that you will find many implementations.  E.g. http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/generic-repository-pattern-entity-framework-asp-net-mvc-and-unit-testing-triangle